# Does React Flux library Alt use React's state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

After completing the [guide](http://alt.js.org/guide) on the Alt site I am confused if Alt uses Reacts state to set properties? In [part 3](http://alt.js.org/guide/store/) - using Stores, it says

> Instance variables defined anywhere in the store will become the
>   state.

It then puts a variable in the store:

> this.locations = [];

Yet if I go into the main React component and log the state, after locations is given data of course, I get undefined except on the props?

```
loggState() {
  console.log(this.state); // undefined
  console.log(this.locations); // undefined
  console.log(this.props.locations); // [object][object]..
}
```

Can anyone explain the relationship between states and props when using Alt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Alt—and indeed most Flux implementations—the store is a totally different part of your application to your components.

A component *subscribes* to changes in a store, then uses the changed data to update its local state, causing it to re-render.

We derive the initial state of components that use the `LocationStore` from whatever the store's state is when we instantiate the component.

```
getInitialState() {
  return LocationStore.getState();
},
```

Then we set up a subscription, listening for changes to the store.

```
componentDidMount() {
  LocationStore.listen(this.onChange);
},
```

And finally, we use the subscription handler to apply these changes to *the component's* local state. The way you decide to apply each update is totally up to you.

```
onChange(state) {
  this.setState(state);
},
```

Each time we call `this.setState` with a new state, the component will re-render.

You could also use a [higher-order component](https://github.com/altjs/connect-to-stores) to subscribe to the store, then covert the store's state to props and pass them down to a wrapped component, instead. In which case, your component wouldn't need to be stateful at all.